# Replace HashMap String value with regex

Tags: java, regex, dictionary, replace

I have a `HashMap<key, value>` where the `value` is a long String query like this: `"localhost:5555/?deviceId=<deviceId>&timeStamp=<timeStamp>&userName=<userName>"` and so on.

Then I have another `HashMap<key2, value2>`

`key2` values would match all char sequences in the long string that have diamond brackets <> around them and I want to replace them with `value2`

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: could you provide an example of the second map and the result you're triyng to get?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but for manipulating URL query parameters, consider using `URIBuilder` from J2EE or from Apache HTTPComponents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for regular expressions:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : map1.entrySet()) {
    String value1 = entry1.getValue();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : map2.entrySet()) {
        String key2 = entry2.getKey();
        String value2 = entry2.getValue();
        String newValue = value1.replace('<' + key2 + '>', value2);
        map1.put(entry1.getKey(), newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking in this direction originally but I thought there could be some other way using regex. In any case this works perfectly well, thank you for the solution.

Comment: When there's a simple solution, I think it's best to avoid regexes. They often complicate things and are harder to review.